# Querying Partitioned Db2 Table

Tags: sql, db2, partition, mainframe, database-partitioning

I am trying to select data from specific partitions of a DB2 Table.

I got this from the DB2 Catalog:

```
Partitioning Info for Table : GMMOM.FINDATA

Column Name     Column Type     Length     Scale     Seq
-----------     -----------     ------     -----     ----
BRANCH          INTEGER          4          0         A
ACCOUNT         INTEGER          4          0         A
DATE_CREATED    DATE             0          0         A


Limit KEY Info for Table : GMMOM.FINDATA


Part             L Part          Rows      LimitKey Value
-----------     -----------     ------     -----------
1                 1                -1        10001
2                 2                -1        10053
3                 3                -1        10095,20082
4                 4                -1        10205,27021
```

What do 2 values (Comma Separated) in LimitKey Value mean?

Appreciate all your help. Thanks

Comment: You may hit [PH44119](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PH44119). Check it with your DBA. Look at the description of `LIMITKEY` column of [SYSIBM.SYSTABLEPART](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=tables-systablepart).

Comment: I have deleted my answer. I misunderstood what you're asking for, and I could not find the answer. Sorry